# rails-4 autocomplete and devise authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, rubygems

I have a problem with the gem rails4-autocomplete. This works perfectly but since I have installed Devise for users I need to be connected to use autocompletion otherwise it does not work.

Indeed, if I withdraw the "Before_action: authenticate_user!" in the application_controller.rb, it works but I can not remove it.

How to skip authentication on rails4-autocomplete as on a method like to skip 
authentication on index and show

Skip_before_action: authenticate_user !, only: [: index,: show]

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have figured this out by now, but the secret to your question is to run

```
rake routes
```

You'll notice that there is a named route created for your autocomplete.  Then you'll just whitelist that method name (which you'll glean from the routing table)

So take a look at the routes, the one with "autocomplete" at the front of it is the one you need.

Then in the controller where your autocomplete is processed add a whitelist for devise if its on that action, like so:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only [:index, :autocomplete_brand_website]
```

I threw together an example app that illustrates how this works in its most simplistic form:

https://bitbucket.org/bunglify/so-autocomplete-devise/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can skip before_action on certain actions using except paramether:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

also you can skip before_action that was inherited using skip_before_action in UsersController:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show]
```